# Количество конечных нулей в факториале js

Tags: javascript

Программа считает конечные нули n!
Проблема такая: первый тест всегда выдает undefined, но все последующие значения считает верно. В чем может быть ошибка?[image]
Заранее спасибо.

```
function zeros(n){
   zeros = n => {
   counter = 0;
    for (i = 5; n/i >= 1; i *= 5)
   counter += Math.floor(n/i);
 return counter;
  };
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вызов ничего не возвращает, но переопределяет переменную `zeros`. Второй и последующие - вызывают эту новую функцию, которая вычисляет и возвращает `counter`.

```
function zeros(n) {
  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = 5; n/i >= 1; i *= 5)
    counter += Math.floor(n/i);
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: да, кажется, не разобралась в стрелочной функции.
Спасибо большое,заработало!